# Rails: DateTime.strptime need 12 hour no-padding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to parse a fingerprint reader's xml file using Datetime.strptime but the times are 12 hour not padded and there seems to be no strftime option to read this. I tried %-I but it did not work.

From the API

```
Time (Hour, Minute, Second, Subsecond):
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, zero-padded (00..23)
  %k - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, blank-padded ( 0..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, zero-padded (01..12)
  %l - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, blank-padded ( 1..12)
```

a snippet from the xml packet

```
<ROW Pin="142" Name="142" sTime="8/12/2013 8:14 PM" VerifyFlag="Fingerpint" MachineName="Office" Abnormite=""/>
<ROW Pin="163" Name="163" sTime="8/12/2013 8:16 PM" VerifyFlag="Fingerpint" MachineName="Office" Abnormite=""/>
<ROW Pin="103" Name="103" sTime="8/13/2013 12:03 AM" VerifyFlag="Fingerpint" MachineName="Office" Abnormite=""/>
<ROW Pin="101" Name="101" sTime="8/13/2013 12:03 AM" VerifyFlag="Fingerpint" MachineName="Office" Abnormite=""/>
<ROW Pin="401" Name="401" sTime="8/13/2013 12:36 AM" VerifyFlag="Fingerpint" MachineName="Office" Abnormite=""/>
<ROW Pin="505" Name="505" sTime="8/13/2013 2:17 AM" VerifyFlag="Fingerpint" MachineName="Office" Abnormite=""/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be parsing fine, using the `%l` option.

**2:17 AM**

```
> DateTime.strptime("8/13/2013 2:17 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")
 => Tue, 13 Aug 2013 02:17:00 +0000
```

**2:17 PM**

```
> DateTime.strptime("8/13/2013 2:17 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")                                                                                 
 => Tue, 13 Aug 2013 14:17:00 +0000
```